# JQuery - Improper recalculate on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote a CSS class to create relative position related to the document instead of the parent element.  To do this I use jQuery to set the "left" property.

```
$(function() {
    var popoutPosition = $('.lw-popout').offset();
    $(".lw-popout").css("left", "-" + popoutPosition.left + "px" );
});
```

This works great.  The problem is it breaks when the window is resized.  I have tried the code below, but it does not work.  It runs on resize, but the value it calculates is not correct.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var popoutPosition = $('.lw-popout').offset();
    $(".lw-popout").css("left", "-" + popoutPosition.left + "px" );
});
```

Comment: Please consider fixing your question title, since it describes the solved part, not the unsolved part.

Comment: So, when the window resizes, the "left" style is already in effect and will change when `offset` returns. You could unset `left` first

Comment: Could you elaborate or post an example Garr?

Answer (score 1):

your code is only going to work for a single element. If you have multiple elements of that class, they are all going to use the offset of the first element.

`offset` gives an offset from the document, which is affected by css styles such as `left`. So once you set it, your technique won't work again until you set `left` back to the original value.

It might be better to use the offset of the parent instead of its own offset.

More clarity:
Say that in the DOM, the element starts out 100 pixels from the left, which is determined by calling `offset()`.

You then set the `left` style to "-100px".

Calling offset() again will result in 0, because that is the new position relative to the document.

If you resize the window, the element may move. Perhaps it should now be at 200 pixels from the left, but because the `left` attribute is set to '-100px', `offset()` actually gives you a left value of 100. It will always be off.

Possible solutions:

- Use `translatex` instead of `left`. That moves where the element appears, but doesn't change the actual position in the dom. it will not affect future calls to `offset`: ie: `transform: translateX(-200px)`
- Set `left` to `0px` before calling `offset`. That will reset to the default and it can then be calculated properly.
- Use `position: fixed` and set `left` to 0.
- Use the parent position to determine where to position the element. If it has a fixed position within the parent it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The way this will be used, if multiple elements use the class, their left offset should always be the same value.  So using the value from the first, should be okay.

Comment: I updated to be sure you understood what the problem was. There are many possible solutions, only some of which I listed out.